# How to use prototype pattern in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a simple scenario as below :

On HTML page, there is a simple table which displays a list of items. This grid has select all checkbox like functionality.

When use click checkbox, all the items in the grid should be selected.

I am using below script for start:

```
(function (window, $) {

    var UnfreezeTest = function () {
        return new UnfreezeTest.init();
    }

    //Create prototype to add new methods here 

    UnfreezeTest.prototype = {
        selectAll: function (chkAllElement) {
            $(".js-chk input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", chkAllElement.checked);
        },
        reset: function () { 

        }
    };

    UnfreezeTest.init = function () {
        //Initialize any object here 
        //Example 
        //this.propertyName = value;
    }

    //Assign prototype for newly created object to point to the methods
    UnfreezeTest.init.prototype = UnfreezeTest.prototype;

    window.UnfreezeTest = UnfreezeTest;


} (window, jQuery));
```

I do not want to use `new` operator while creating an object.

I want to use as below:

```
var obj = UnfreezeTest();
```

Is there any suggestion or am I doing it right?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. In a code review, I would say that `return new UnfreezeTest.init()` and `UnfreezeTest.init.prototype = UnfreezeTest.prototype` are wrong, except you can give a good reason why you have done that, not because it would not work, but because it does not make any sense right now that you do it this way.

Comment: I want to create prototype. So all object created share same methods. So any suggestion what above code is doing ? And what is right way doing it? Could you provide some light ?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that `new`?

Comment: What is the significance of the unused `window` parameter, and is the `jQuery` instance parameter loaded in in the same window as the code (i.e. why is it there) ? Also is the code working? If so you may have posted on the wrong forum.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, in order to create instances of your prototypes I think you want something more like the following:

```js
var UnfreezeTest = function (tableId) {
 this.tableId = tableId;
}

UnfreezeTest.prototype = {
 selectAll: function (chkAllElement) {
  $('#' + this.tableId + " .js-chk input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", chkAllElement.checked);
 },
 reset: function () { 

 }
};

var unfreeze1 = new UnfreezeTest('myTable1');
unfreeze1.selectAll();


var unfreeze2 = new UnfreezeTest('myTable2');
unfreeze2.selectAll();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i do not want use new operator while creating an object. I want to use as below : var obj = UnfreezeTest();

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is "no, you are not doing it right".

The reasoning is

- `UnfreezeTest` is a factory function, not a constructor. It returns an object. Hence calling it with `new UnfreezeTest()` makes no difference - it returns an instance of `UnfreezeTest.init` which the `new` operator used in call will pass back to the caller.
- `UnfreezeTest.init` is the constructor. Any prototype properties of its instances should be set on `UnfreezeTest.init.prototype`.
- Setting inherited properties on `UnfreezeTest.prototype` and then setting `UnfreezeTest.init.prototype` to `UnfreezeTest.prototype`, and then returning an instance of `UnfreezeTest.init` from a call to `UnfreezeTest`  is an exercise in **obfuscation**.

Comment: Unfortunately i do not understand what you are saying. Could you please take time to explain the concept and hiw to do ot right way?

Comment: You modified the question after this answer was posted. Why do you want to avoid using `new` before calls to `UnfreezeTest`? My recommendation would be to throw an error if `UnfreezeTest` is not called as a constructor rather than softly doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

If the only aim is to be able to create an instance of that calls with and without `new` then you can do it that way:

```js
function UnfreezeTest(tableId) {
  // check if this is an instance of UnfreezeTest
  if( !(this instanceof UnfreezeTest) ) {
    // if it is not then the function was not invoked with new so create an instance
    return new UnfreezeTest(tableId) 
  }
  this.tableId = tableId;
}

UnfreezeTest.prototype = {
  selectAll: function (chkAllElement) {
    $('#' + this.tableId + " .js-chk input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", chkAllElement.checked);
  },
  reset: function () { 

  }
};


console.dir(UnfreezeTest(1234))
console.dir(new UnfreezeTest(1234))
```

But I do not recommend that pattern because it hurts maintainability, do not break common language pattern just because you do not like to use `new`. I would suggest using an explicit factory function instead:

```js
function UnfreezeTest(tableId) {
  this.tableId = tableId;
}

UnfreezeTest.prototype = {
  selectAll: function (chkAllElement) {
    $('#' + this.tableId + " .js-chk input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", chkAllElement.checked);
  },
  reset: function () { 

  }
};

function createUnfreezeTest(teableId) {
  return new UnfreezeTest(teableId)
}


console.dir(createUnfreezeTest(1234))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another pattern you can use, which doesn't require a prototype or the word 
'new' is the following:

```js
function UnfreezeTest(tableId) {
 var tableId = tableId;
 var obj = {
  selectAll: function (chkAllElement) {
   $('#' + tableId + " .js-chk input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", chkAllElement.checked);
  },
  reset: function () { 

  }
 };
 return obj;
}

var unfreeze = UnfreezeTest(tableId);
```